# Como validar usuario con sistema de logueo usando hash de contraseña

Tags: php, mysqli

Poseo un sistema de logueo donde quiero agregar el HASH de contraseñas ya tengo la opcion de crear y insertar el hash generado a la base de datos, pero ahora no se como debo verificar si la contraseña es correcta, hago un select? o utilizo password_verify?

```
    <?php
session_start();

//Verifico que CONECTAR tenga un valor, esto para validar que este activo javascript//

$conectar = 1;

if ($conectar == 1) {
    include '__conexion.php';
    include_once 'funciones/passwordLib.php';

    $usuario = $_POST['txtusuario'];

    echo "usuario: ".$usuario."<br>";

    $contrasena_t =$_POST['txtcontrasena'];

    echo "contrasena: ".$contrasena_t."<br>";

    $hash=password_hash($contrasena_t);

    echo "Hash: ".$hash."<br>";

    $sql = ("SELECT contrasena FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=?");
            $stmt  = $conexion->prepare($sql);
            $stmt ->bind_param('s', $usuario);
            $stmt ->execute();
            $stmt ->bind_result($contraseña_bd);
            $stmt ->fetch();
            $num= $stmt->num_rows;
            echo "numero de fregist".$num."<br>";
            echo "Contraseña de la bd con ese usuario".$contraseña_bd."<br>";
            if ($stmt->num_rows === 0) {
                // MENSAJE DE ACCESO NEGADO //
                /*echo ('<script>alert("Usuario o Contraseña incorrecto, vuelva a ingresar");</script>');
                echo ("<script>window.location = 'index.php';</script>");
                exit;*/
                // ------------------------ //
                echo "No hay contraseña para ese usuario"."<br>";
            }else if(password_verify($contrasena_t, $contraseña_bd)){ //contraseña post y hash//
                echo "Contraseñas iguales";
                $stmt = $conexion->prepare("SELECT nivel_id,unidad_id from usuarios WHERE usuario=? AND contrasena=?");
                $stmt->bind_param('ss', $usuario, $contrasena_t);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->store_result();
                $stmt->bind_result($nivel_id,$unidad_id);
                while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                }
                $_SESSION['nivel'] = $nivel_id;
                $_SESSION['conectado'] = true; //esta conectado//
                $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
                $_SESSION['unidad'] = $unidad_id;
                $_SESSION['inicio'] = time();
                $_SESSION['expira'] = $_SESSION['inicio'] + (10 * 60); //TIEMPO DE SESIÓN//
                if ($nivel_id == 0) {
                // MENSAJE DE BIENVENIDA //
                /*echo ('<script>alert("Bienvenido al Sistema Automatizado de OMD");</script>');
                echo ("<script>window.location = 'menu_unidades.php';</script>");*/
                // --------------------- //
                }
                elseif ($nivel_id == 1) {
                // MENSAJE DE BIENVENIDA //
            /*  echo ('<script>alert("Bienvenido al Sistema Automatizado de OMD");</script>');
                echo ("<script>window.location = 'menu_administradores.php';</script>");*/
                // --------------------- //
                }
            }
        }else
        {
            echo "contraseñas desiguales";
            /*echo ('<script>alert("No tiene permisos suficientes para acceder a esta parte del sistema");</script>');
            echo ("<script>window.location = 'index.php';</script>");*/
        }

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para verificar tu `Hash`, debes selecionar tu `Hash` desde tu `Base de datos` y lo comparas con la contraseña introducido por el usuario.

**Ejemplo:**

```
<?php

    //Contraseña Hash, obtenido desde tu Base datos.
    $contrasena_BD = $2y$07$BCryptRequires22Chrcte/VlQH0piJtjXl.0t1XkA8pw9dMXTpOq';

    if (password_verify($_POST['txtcontrasena'], $contrasena_BD)) {
        echo '¡La contraseña es válida!';
    } else {
        echo 'La contraseña no es válida.';
    }
?>
```

[Manual password_verify](http://php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php)

**Ejemplo con tu código optimizado:**

```
<?php

if ($conectar == 1) {

    include '__conexion.php';
    include_once 'funciones/passwordLib.php';

    //Datos formulario
    $usuario = $_POST['txtusuario'] ?: '';
    $contrasena = $_POST['txtcontrasena'] ?: '';

    //Sentencia.
    $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT contrasena,nivel_id,unidad_id FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=? LIMIT 1");
    $statement->bind_param('s', $usuario);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->store_result();
    if ($statement->num_rows === 0) {

        $statement->close();//Cerramos sentencia.

        // MENSAJE DE ACCESO NEGADO //
        echo ('<script>alert("Usuario o Contraseña incorrecto, vuelva a ingresar");</script>');
        echo ("<script>window.location = 'index.php';</script>");
        exit;

    } else { #verdadero comparación.

        //Obtenemos resultados desde Base de datos.
        $statement->bind_result($contrasena_BD,$nivel_id,$unidad_id);
        while ($statement->fetch()) {

            if (password_verify($_POST['txtcontrasena'], $contrasena_BD)) {

                $_SESSION['nivel'] = $nivel_id;
                $_SESSION['conectado'] = true; //esta conectado//
                $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
                $_SESSION['unidad'] = $unidad_id;
                $_SESSION['inicio'] = time();
                $_SESSION['expira'] = $_SESSION['inicio'] + (10 * 60); //TIEMPO DE SESIÓN//

                if ($nivel_id == 0) {
                    // MENSAJE DE BIENVENIDA //
                    echo ('<script>alert("Bienvenido al Sistema Automatizado de OMD");</script>');
                    echo ("<script>window.location = 'menu_unidades.php';</script>");

                } elseif ($nivel_id == 1) {
                    // MENSAJE DE BIENVENIDA //
                    echo ('<script>alert("Bienvenido al Sistema Automatizado de OMD");</script>');
                    echo ("<script>window.location = 'menu_administradores.php';</script>");
                }


            } else { //Contraseña no coincide.
                // MENSAJE DE ACCESO NEGADO //
                echo ('<script>alert("Usuario o Contraseña incorrecto, vuelva a ingresar");</script>');
                echo ("<script>window.location = 'index.php';</script>");
            }


        } $statement->close();//Cerramos sentencia.
    } 
} else {       
    echo ('<script>alert("No tiene permisos suficientes para acceder a esta parte del sistema");</script>');
    echo ("<script>window.location = 'index.php';</script>");
}

?>
```

**Nota:**  `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` (`integer`)

El algoritmo que se utilizará por defecto si no se especifica otro distinto. Esto puede cambiar en versiones futuras de `PHP`, cuando métodos más nuevos y fuertes de hashing estén disponibles.

    Cabe señalar que con el tiempo esta constante puede (y probablemente lo hará) cambiar. Por tanto, se debería considerar que la longitud del `hash` resultante puede cambiar. Así, si se emplea `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` se debería almacenar el hash resultante de forma que se pueda almacenar más de `60` caracteres (`255` es el ancho recomendado).

[Manual constantes predefinidas](http://php.net/manual/es/password.constants.php)

Comment: actualize mi pregunta,porque tengo un select que obtiene la contraseña del usuario que se ingreso, y esta devuelve la contraseña que esta en base de datos, para compararla con el hash de la que ingreso, pero me dice que hay "0 cero" registros y sin embargo me da la contraseña?, que puede ocurrir.
Dice "no hay registros" y me da la contraseña

Comment: @VictorA. Voy a modificar mi ejemplo con tu código, ya que podrías mejorarlo y optimizarlo, dame un poco de tiempo y la actualizo.

Comment: excelente, por cierto los hash cambian? porque estoy tratando de convertir algunos registros viejos con texto plano (formule otra pregunta http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56660/hash-de-usuarios-en-texto-plano) y creo que cambian

Comment: Sí cambian. El algoritmo de hasheo MCRYPT que actualmente usa password_hash no es determinístico.

Comment: @VictorA. Ya te he actualizado mí ejemplo, cómo te ha mencionado el compañero, si cambian. Cabe señalar que con el tiempo esta constante puede (y probablemente lo hará) cambiar. Por tanto, se debería considerar que la longitud del hash resultante puede cambiar. http://php.net/manual/es/password.constants.php

Comment: @VictorA. Respecto a que te devuelve la contraseña, pero encuentra 0 registros. Fíjate en tu primera sentencia haces un WHERE user=? AND contrasena=?, la comparación de tu contrasena=? siempre te va fallar, mira mi ejemplo actualizado, lo he modificado un poco.

Comment: gracias por la ayuda, no he podido revisar porque estoy lejos de mi pc, mañlana te respondere
por cierto me explicas que significa esto luego de los post ?: ''.

y el hecho de que cambie no significaria que los hash que estan guardados nunca daran TRUE o por ejemplo si el hash de la contraseña 123456 es wrqwrqwrwqr y meten 123456 y da tqwtqwtqwt seran iguales?

Comment: gracias tambien por lo de la contraseña, ya lo corregi jejeje.

Comment: @VictorA. vale, ya comentas si te funciono el ejemplo.  Es un operador condicional *(Operador ternario)* `?:`  para evaluar, mas información: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: ya lo copie a mi sistema, habia un pequeño error de unas llaves del else al final habia dos echos al final pero no tenia llave. Funciona excelente

Comment: utilizar while ($statement->fetch())  es igual al while ($datos= $resultados->fetch_assoc())

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55747/discussion-between-d-bulten-and-victor-a).

Comment: @VictorA. Me alegro que te haya funcionado, ya que escribi el código rapido, si, es una alternativa, yo personalmente suelo hacer *bind_result()* con *fetch()* para obtener los datos desde la Base de Datos. Un saludo

Comment: me ayudarias con esta otra pregunta, porque ya valida los registros pero no todos los registros de la bd tienen su hash funcional jejeje: http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/56660/hash-de-usuarios-en-texto-plano/56699#56699