# Hash de usuarios en texto plano

Tags: php, mysqli

Tengo varios registros (unos 300) donde los usuarios tienen su contraseña en texto plano y deseo pasarlo a HASH

utilice un archivo para convertir las contraseñas y luego insertarlas, pero ocurre que algunas quedan en blanco, porque?.

Para verificar que no fuera el password_hash hice un listado con tablas y coloque alli mismo la conversion y todo el listado sale con hash, el problema creo esta en la consulta.

Aqui les dejo ambos archivos:

Hashear.php

```
  <?php

          $stmt =$conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios");
          $stmt->execute();
          $resultados=$stmt->get_result();
          $contador=0;
          while ($datos= $resultados->fetch_assoc()) 
                            $contraseña=$datos["contrasena"];

            $hash=password_hash($contraseña);

    $stmt = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE usuarios SET hash=? WHERE contrasena=?"); 

  $stmt->bind_param("ss",$hash,$contraseña);
       $stmt->execute();
       $stmt->close();



        // --------------------------------------- //
          ?>
```

Listado en HTML

```
 <?php

          $stmt =$conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios");
          $stmt->execute();
          $resultados=$stmt->get_result();
          $contador=0;
          while ($datos= $resultados->fetch_assoc()) {
            $contador=$contador+1;
            echo '<td bordercolor="#FFFFFF" align="center" id="" width="1">'.$datos["id_usuario"].'</td>';
            echo '<td bordercolor="#FFFFFF" align="center" id="" width="1">'.$datos["usuario"].'</td>';
            echo '<td bordercolor="#FFFFFF" align="center" id="" width="45">'.$datos["contrasena"].'</td>';

            $contraseña=$datos["contrasena"];

            $hash=password_hash($contraseña);


            echo '<td bordercolor="#FFFFFF" align="center" id="" width="45">'.$hash.'</td>';
            $nivel=$datos["nivel_id"];
            $stmt =$conexion->prepare("SELECT desc_nivel FROM niveles WHERE id_nivel=?");
            $stmt->bind_param("i",$nivel);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->bind_result($desc_nivel); 
            $stmt->fetch();
            $stmt->close();
            echo '<td bordercolor="#FFFFFF" align="center" id="" width="45">'.$desc_nivel.'</td>';
            echo '<td bordercolor="#FFFFFF" align="center" id="" width="45">'.$datos["unidad_id"].'</td>';

            echo "</tr>";
          }
        // --------------------------------------- //
          ?>
```

**Actualizado combinando el codigo sugerido en las respuestas y mi codigo.**

> Muestra "Los datos se actualizaron correctamente". pero no todos los registros >obtenien, esta vez solo los ultimos se generaron con HASh los primeros no:

```
<?php
include '__conexion.php';
  require_once 'funciones/passwordLib.php'; // Libreria de PHP5.5 Hash de contraseñas 
?>

          <?php

          $stmt =$conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios");
          $stmt->execute();
          $resultados=$stmt->get_result();
          while ($datos= $resultados->fetch_assoc()) 
          $contraseña=$datos["contrasena"];
          $hash=password_hash($contraseña,PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
          $stmt = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE usuarios SET hash=? WHERE contrasena=?"); 
          $stmt->bind_param("ss",$hash,$contraseña);
          $comprobar=$stmt->execute();
          //Comprobamos si se ejecuto nuestra sentencia.
          if (false===$comprobar) {
            exit('Nuesta sentencia UPDATE fallo: ' . htmlspecialchars($actualiza->error));
          } else {
            echo "Los datos se actualizaron correctamente.";
          }


          $stmt->close();//Cerramos sentencia 'select'.

         ?>
```

Comment: yo veo que al while le falta una llave de cierre

Comment: podrias fijar el valor por defecto de hash en NULL y así distinguir si está escribiendo un campo en blanco o de plano no está pasando por esa fila. Por otro lado: qué largo le diste al campo hash? Es text o varchar?

Comment: le di un largo de 255, aunque no se si sea porque algunas contraseñas tienen un # numeral, pero solo algunas, lo raro es que en el listado HTML salen toditas con su respectivo HASH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu ejemplo veo dos pequeños fallos, el primero es que en tu `while` se te ha olvidado tus llaves `{}`.

Y el segundo, te falta añadir la **constante** que va usar la función `password_hash()`.

```
//Tu código
$hash=password_hash($contraseña);

//Código actualizado
$hash = password_hash($contraseña,PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

### Actualmente se admiten los siguientes algoritmos:

> **PASSWORD_BCRYPT** se utiliza para crear nuevos `hash` de contraseñas empleando el algoritmo `CRYPT_BLOWFISH`.
>   
>   Siempre resultará en un hash que utiliza el formato criptgráfico "`$2y$`", el cual siempre tiene un ancho de `60`.

o

> **PASSWORD_DEFAULT**, El algoritmo que se utilizará por defecto si no se especifica otro distinto. Esto puede cambiar en versiones futuras de PHP, cuando métodos más nuevos y fuertes de hashing estén disponibles.
>   
>   Así, si se emplea `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` se debería almacenar el hash resultante de forma que se pueda almacenar más de `60` caracteres (`255` es el ancho recomendado).

Más información [manual password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php)

**Un posible ejemplo:**

```
       <?php
  //Tu conexión.
  require_once('conexion.php');

  //Sentencia.
  $stmt = $c->prepare("SELECT contrasena FROM usuarios");//Selecciono solo los datos a utilizar, en tu caso la contraseña.
  //Ejecutar sentencia.
  $stmt->execute();
  //Ligamos resultado BD.
  $stmt->bind_result($contrasena_txt_plano);
  while ($stmt->fetch()) {

    //Creamos nuestro Hash.
    $hash = password_hash($contrasena_txt_plano, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);//BCRYPT, que tendrá siempre 60 caracteres. (¡Imporante comprobar que tu columna contrasena en caso varchar pueda obtener 60 caracteres!

    //Creo un array, con el hash y la contrasena de texto plano.
    $arr[] = ['contrasena' => $contrasena_txt_plano, 'hash' => $hash]; 


  } $stmt->close();//Cerramos sentencia 'select'.

  //var_dump($arr);

  //Recorremos el array, para hacer nuestro 'UPDATE'.
  for ($i=0; $i<count($arr); $i++) { 

    //Actualizamos datos.
    $actualiza = $c->prepare("UPDATE usuarios SET hash=? WHERE contrasena=?");    
    $actualiza->bind_param("ss",$arr[$i]['hash'],$arr[$i]['contrasena']);

    $comprobar = $actualiza->execute();

    //Comprobamos si se ejecuto nuestra sentencia.
    if (false===$comprobar) {
      exit('Nuesta sentencia UPDATE fallo: ' . htmlspecialchars($actualiza->error));
    } else {
      echo "Los datos se actualizaron correctamente.<br />";
    }

    $actualiza->close();    

  }
?>
```

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, ya cree los campos varchar 255 para los HASH, me recomiendas que use blowfish o el default?

Comment: sobre esa parte la habia olvidado

Comment: lo coloque pero no inserto el hash para todos los elementos, publicare como actualize mi codigo

Comment: tu respuesta me da error en     $actualiza->bind_param("ss",$hash,$contrasena_txt_plano);

Comment: @VictorA. Asi a simple visto no veo ningun fallo en mi código, revisa la sentencia aver si hay algun nombre diferente a tu tabla usuarios, luego lo reviso mejor, que estoy desde el movil. ¿Que error en concreto te lanza?

Comment: el error concreto es este: Error suppression ignored for Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in line 20 ->  $actualiza->bind_param("ss",$hash,$contrasena_txt_plano);

Comment: @Victor prueba hacer un var_dump($actualiza); despues de la linea de tu sentencia prepare, aver que información te da. En principio te esta diciendo que tu sentencia no es un objeto, asi que no se puede llamar a *bind_param()*.

Comment: object(mysqli_stmt)[2]
  public 'affected_rows' => null
  public 'insert_id' => null
  public 'num_rows' => null
  public 'param_count' => null
  public 'field_count' => null
  public 'errno' => null
  public 'error' => null
  public 'error_list' => null
  public 'sqlstate' => null
  public 'id' => null

para $stmt y boolean false para actualiza
 me sale, y me di cuenta que mi codigo solo convirtio los que tenian la contraseña de 123456789 y son varios, el resto los dejo vacios

Comment: @VictorA. Te he modificado mi ejemplo, estuve haciendo pruebas en `localhost`, creí la tabla idéntica, y me lanzo el mismo *error*. Entonces encontré la solución de crear un `array` con dichos datos y luego recorriendo dicho `array` hacemos el `update`, y funciono bien, me actualizo correctamente todas las contraseñas *(tanto 1234567, 1234$gee, %gsffr23S, etc.…)*.

Comment: GRACIAS por modificarlo, entonces el error porque? la cantidad de archivos? la forma en la que se presentaban?, actualmente no tengo el sistema jejeje y tengo de mouse mi tablet, asi que sera dificil revisarlo, por otro lado, me ayudarias en mi pregunta del filtro de busqueda, es para tener busqueda dinamica con mysqli,

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55787/discussion-between-d-bulten-and-victor-a).

Comment: supongo que ya sirve... pero Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded. hay por cierto contraseñas asi:  
#DELGADO y asi JAFAJF42

Comment: ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes SOLUCION

Comment: @VictorA. Me alegro que al final lo solucionaste, yo ice una prueba donde solo actualize 15 registros. En tu caso me imagino que tendras mucho registros a actualizar.

Comment: pues sip, duro como 3 minutos, oye me ayudas con mi pregunta de las consultas jejeje ya logre pasar los parametros y los identificadores pero no devuelve resultaos